# Should I combine two 5-star items?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

So after buying some Relic Draw Drops, I ended up with two [One Winged Angels](https://ffrkstrategy.gamematome.jp/game/951/wiki/Equipment_Rarity%205_One-Winged%20Angel%20%28VII%29).

Am I better off combining these to get the Augment boost; or am I better served by just leveling up the second one to 20 and having two characters be able to use them?

Comment: This depends. Who would wield them and what other high-level weapons do you have available?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what other equipment you have and what your party members can use.  If everything else you have is garbage, then it is fine to temporarily have two One Winged Angels.  As you get more equipment though, it will be more useful to have the single upgraded item instead.

Since you will eventually combine the items, the only thing you really lose is the crafting materials which are pretty easily acquired.

Comment: Since One Winged Angels are katanas, there's also a limited number of characters that can utilize them at all, let alone utilize them well. Luckily, OWA is great on Sephiroth due to the soul break, and Cloud can equip Katanas and has great stats and available skills. So, keeping or combining them will also hinge on his party makeup.

Comment: @Ellesedil For some reason I feel like almost all of my high level physical characters are able to use Katanas so I didn't really think about that much.  I added that into my first sentence but I feel it to be a minor point.

Comment: A couple more considerations:  Will you have two katana users in your party at the same time? If not, it may be better to combine the OWAs.  Do you frequently use a retaliate strategy? If so, it may be better to combine the OWAs as you want your retaliator to have the highest ATK possible and any other melee character could use something as weak as a 1\* dagger because all they are doing is attacking the retaliator, so the damage from the weapon is irrelevant.

Comment: @Tom Point 1 is already taken into account in my answer in the first line.  Point 2 though I'm not so sure about.  If the User thinks they need 2 Katanas, either they already are not doing the retaliate strat or they haven't honed it enough to take advantage of it.